# Image selector not working in p-editor (Primeng)

Tags: angular, editor, primeng, quill

I am using Primeng in my angular project. By default p-editor didn't show image selector. So, I tried to customize by adding the selector. Still, other selector are shown except the one that I wanted. (image)

[image]

**Below is my code:**

```
 <p-editor required [(ngModel)]="comment.comment" placeholder="{{ 'comment' | translate }}" name="comment"
        class="pEditor" [style]="{ height: '180px', 'font-size': '1.2em' }">
        <p-header>

          <span class="ql-formats">
            <select class="ql-size">
              <option value="24px">24</option>
              <option value="48px">48</option>
              <option value="100px">100</option>
              <option value="200px">200</option>
            </select>
          </span>
          <span class="ql-formats">
            <button class="ql-bold" aria-label="Bold"></button>
            <button class="ql-italic" aria-label="Italic"></button>
            <button class="ql-underline" aria-label="Underline"></button>
            <button class="ql-strike" aria-label="Strike"></button>
          </span>

          <span class="ql-formats">
            <button aria-label="Link" class="ql-link"></button>
            <button aria-label="Image" class="ql-image"></button>  //Not working
          </span>
        </p-header>
      </p-editor>
```

Comment: please check your tags

Comment: Aren't those the related tags? @Kukeltje

Comment: no, check the info pages about the tags... (and don't be 'mislead' by the url you dowload things from or view showcases on)